# Running a for loop and the last value appears only after I press the Enter key

Tags: c++, for-loop, input

Given pairs of integers, I'm writing a program that goes through each pair, finds the minimum, and displays that minimum. The following link is an image of the program results.

[image: Image of program results]

The issue I'm having is that the for loop doesn't display all the results at once--the last result is always missing. It is only after I press the Enter key that it displays the last result.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() 
{
    //using declarations
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std:: endl;

    // variables
    // signed int to test for negative values as well
    int numOfPairs;
    signed int firstNum, secondNum;

    // prompt user
    cout << "data:" << endl;
    cin >> numOfPairs;

    // answer display
    cout << endl << "answer:" << endl;

    // for each pair of numbers find the minimum
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPairs; i++){
        cin >> firstNum >> secondNum;
        if (firstNum > secondNum)
        {
            cout << secondNum << " ";
        }
        else if (secondNum > firstNum)
        {
            cout << firstNum << " ";
        }
    }

    // exit code
    return 0;
}
```

**Here is my result:**

[image: my results]

I tried using a while loop, but I experienced the same problem (pressing the Enter key to receive the last result). 
My guess is that it either -

(1) has to do with how I process user input and plug them into the input stream (to create the `firstNum` and `secondNum` variables)

or

(2) the way I use `numOfPairs` as part of the condition statement in the for loop.

Comment: [don't put text in images like that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714). Copy and paste them here

Comment: @JohnZwinck How does `flush`ing even help? The problem is `cin` waiting for input.

Comment: You are expecting all inputs at once and then all outputs, but this code is combination of input output,  input output...use pairs instead and then iterate over the pairs

Comment: @VidorVistrom Thanks Vidor! I decided to use an array to grab all the values in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're inputting this:

```
3<Enter>
5 3<Enter>
2 8<Enter>
100 15
```

And then you expect the program to process all the rows, including `100 15` which has not had Enter pressed.

This won't work, because the runtime can't know that you aren't in the middle of a number, for example you might be entering `100 150`.

You need to press Enter after each and every line, including the last one.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks John!